# How to restart script from the beginning?

Tags: ruby

I decided to make a number-guessing game. Here is the code.

```
print "Guess a number from 1-20. You have 5 guesses!"
guess1=gets.chomp
guess1=guess1.to_i
random=1 + rand(20)
random=random.to_i
if guess1 == random
  puts "Correct! You win!!!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
elsif guess1 > random
  puts "Wrong! Too high. Try again!"
else
  puts "Wrong! Too low. Try again!"
end
guess2=gets.chomp
guess2=guess2.to_i
if guess2 == random
  puts "Correct! You win!!!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
elsif guess2 > random
  puts "Wrong! Too high. Try again!"
else
  puts "Wrong! Too low. Try again!"
end
guess3=gets.chomp
guess3=guess3.to_i
if guess3 == random
  puts "Correct! You win!!!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
elsif guess3 > random
  puts "Wrong! Too high. Try again!"
else
  puts "Wrong! Too low. Try again!"
end
guess4=gets.chomp
guess4=guess4.to_i
if guess4 == random
  puts "Correct! You win!!!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
elsif guess4 > random
  puts "Wrong! Too high. Try again!"
else
  puts "Wrong! Too low. Try again!"
end
guess5=gets.chomp
guess5=guess5.to_i
if guess5 == random
  puts "Correct! You win!!!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
elsif guess5 > random
  puts "Wrong! Too high. Game over!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
else
  puts "Wrong! Too low. Game over!"
  sleep(5)
  Kernel.exit
end
```

How would I add a try-again option at the end that would restart the game?

Comment: Now you need to learn about methods. Extract your game logic into a method, which you can call (thus "restarting" the game).

Comment: Also take a look a loops and iterations in Ruby. If you placa a while loop around the hole code it would almost have the desired effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sergio said, a very clean solution would be to learn about functions, and divide up your game logic, so that you can call the function(s) when needed.

Another solution would be to use [loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), specifically a [do...while loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop).

*Side note: The `begin...while` style of looping in the tutorial link I posted is not recommended by [Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto), the creator of Ruby. He recommends the `loop do...break end` style, which is what I will demonstrate.*

I'll let you read the tutorials to learn more about whats going on, but the gist is that this particular style of loop will run your code once, and it will either loop back and run it again, or exit the loop and the program will end, depending on the result of our "control" variable.

Unfortunately, because of the way you've written your code, wrapping the program in a simple `do...while` is very awkward because of the `Kernel.exit` lines, and the fact that you've hard coded 5 guesses which are run in sequence. Since my answer involves loops, I'll quickly show you a good way to refactor the code without too much pain. Please note the comments in the code to understand what's going on.

```
loop do # The start of the main game loop
  random=1 + rand(20)
  random=random.to_i

  guess_count = 0 # Tracks the number of times the user has guessed

  print "Guess a number from 1-20. You have 5 guesses!"
  while guess_count < 5 # The guess loop; keep looping up to a max of 5 times
    guess=gets.chomp
    guess=guess.to_i

    if guess == random
        puts "Correct! You win!!!"
        sleep(5) # 5 seconds is a very long time, I would reduce this to 1 at most
        break # This causes the 'guess loop' to end early
    elsif guess > random
        puts "Wrong! Too high. Try again!"
    else
        puts "Wrong! Too low. Try again!"
    end

    guess_count+= 1 # increment the guess count if the user guessed incorrectly
  end

  puts "Would you like to play again? (y/n)"
  play_again = gets.chomp

  break if play_again != "y" # exit the main loop if the user typed anything except "y"
end # The end of the main loop, and thus the entire program
# No need for Kernal.exit. The program is done at this point.
```

*Note: I removed your comments so they don't interfere with the explanation. Feel free to put them back in your version.*

Take a look at loops in the tutorials for more details. Hope thats clear.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the thorough reply. I knew about loops, but didn't understand how to use them. Now I do. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! Don't forget to accept an answer (green checkmark to the left of the answer), whichever one helped you best.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is make the main thread of your game a loop:

```
loop do
  # Prompt
end
```

This will execute endlessly whatever is inside it until an exception is raised or the program is interrupted.

Now, to make it effective, you'll want to start wrapping up your game logic in an Object.

For instance

```
class GuessingGame
  def initialize
    @secret = 1 + rand(20)
    @guesses_remaining = 5
  end

  def is_it?(number)
    @guesses_remaining -+ 1
    @secret == number
  end
end
```

Now, when you start the game look, you just make `GuessingGame.new`, and after the game is over, by running out of guesses, or getting it right, you can just prompt to retry and make a new guessing game

Answer (score 2):

First, extract the repeated part into a method:

```
def correctly_guessed?(target)
  guess = gets.to_i
  if    guess == target then puts "Correct! You win!!!"; sleep(5)
  elsif guess > target  then puts "Wrong! Too high. Try again!"
  else                       puts "Wrong! Too low. Try again!"
  end
end
```

Then, restructure your code:

```
loop do
  print "Guess a number from 1-20. You have 5 guesses!"
  target = 1 + rand(20)
  5.times{break if correctly_guessed?(target)}
  print "Restart the game? (Y to restart)"
  break unless gets.chomp == "Y"
end
```